# How to sum values in arrays with key in other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object with two arrays in JSON file :

```
"Data": {
        "Server": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"],
        "Count": ["12", "32", "7", "1", "67", "2", "3", "6", "5", "6", "5", "4"]
    }
```

what I want to achive is to add all values of array 'count' for relative values in 'server' array and create new array with structure like this:

```
 "Data": {
            "Server": ["a", "b", "c"],
            "Count": ["52", "78", "20"]
        }
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: show your current code

Comment: show us what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to do something like this:

```
<?php

$object = json_decode("your json here");
$server = $object->Server;
$count = $object->Count;

$tmp = [];

for( $i = 0; $i < $server; $i++){
    $tmp[$server[$i]] += $count[$i];
}

$data = new stdClass();
$data->Server = array_keys($tmp);
$data->Count = array_values($tmp);

$json = json_encode($data);
```

But personally I would rather build a structure like:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Servers": {
            "a":52,
            "b":78,
            "c":20
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry guys for mess with my question, but I couldn't show all the code it's to big. This post aswered my question. Thanks!